# Sample size selection (sample to generally represent population traits)

Tags: estimation, sampling

Let's say I have 100,000 images total. I have around 15 categories for the images. I do not know how the 100,000 are distributed across these categories.

I'd like to select N images at random, then manually classify them and arrive at an approximate of how my 100k images are grouped into the 15 categories. Eg, cat1: 5%, cat2:3%, cat3:10%, ..... cat15:8%

What's the best rule for calculating N, so that my sample's distribution over the 15 categories, represents the population reasonably well?

Answer (score 0):

Arrived at a reasonable guess for N through simulation: N of around 400 gives strong directional results of the population distribution.

```
import random
from collections import Counter

items = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'plane', 'circus', 'turtle', 'oven', 'food', 'running', 'hello']
weights=[10, 20, 35, 5, 18, 3, 19, 4, 5, 12]

pop_counter = Counter(random.choices(items,  weights=weights, k=100000)).most_common(10) # Our population

# Get the populatino into a list
population = []

for item, count in pop_counter:
    population.extend([item] * count)

assert(len(population) == 100000)

# Print out the %'s
for item, count in pop_counter:
    print(item, count/100000)

bird 0.26634
cat 0.15414
oven 0.14347
circus 0.13777
hello 0.09207
dog 0.07775
plane 0.03826
running 0.03777
food 0.03081
turtle 0.02162

for item, count in Counter(random.sample(population=population, k=400)).most_common():
    print(item, count/400)

bird 0.2425
circus 0.165
cat 0.155
oven 0.1475
hello 0.105
dog 0.0875
running 0.035
food 0.0325
plane 0.0175
turtle 0.0125
```